# Download .NET framework 4.0 updates

Tags: .net

in one of the system .NET framwork 4.0 is installed, but to me it seems that it is a very old version. 
The clr.dll version is 4.0.30319.1.

How can i get the latest updates on this framework 4.0 without the "Windows Update" option. 
Is there any installer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download it independently on MS website
Search in google with ".NET framework [version you want]", google will show you the result that you can down the framework on MSWebsite

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to install .NET Framework 4.5, which is an in-place, backwards-compatible version of the .NET 4.0 framework. You can find the installer here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: It's not always an option. Eg: if you need to deploy your app at client side it might cause problems to replace .NET4 with .NET4.5 ...

Comment: @AndrasSebö no it doesn't.

Comment: @CodeCaster We upgraded to .NET 4.5.1 and it introduced problems in our apps that targeted .NET 4.0. So things ARE different in .NET 4.5 than 4.0.

Comment: @Smitty "problems" isn't really specific, is it? :-) If there are breaking changes in a. NET upgrade, MS will notify us of that. Otherwise it are bugs that will be fixed, as. NET aims to be backwards compatible, or you had code that relied on unspecified behaviour, for example using reflection to rely on inner workings.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version is: 4.0.30319.544

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103